# SweetAlert2 cierra cuadro al dar click fuera de este

Tags: formularios, sweetalert2

Trato de que el usuario se vea "obligado" a dar su nombre para poder acceder al contenido, Quiero que no se cierre al dar click fuera del cuadro (soy nuevo en esto)

```js
window.onload = function (){(Swal
    .fire({
        title: "Tu nombre",
        input: "text",
        confirmButtonText: "Continuar",
    })
    .then(resultado => {
        if (resultado.value) {
            let nombre = resultado.value;
            swal.fire("Hola " + nombre + "tu sinceridad es de mucha ayuda. ");
        }
    }))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la sulucion esta en agregar:"allowOutsideClick: false,", en las propiedades de tu mensaje swal.
Estaria Solucionado asi:

```js
window.onload = function (){(Swal
    .fire({
        title: "Tu nombre",
        input: "text",
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        confirmButtonText: "Continuar",
    })
    .then(resultado => {
        if (resultado.value) {
            let nombre = resultado.value;
            swal.fire("Hola " + nombre + "tu sinceridad es de mucha ayuda. ");
        }
    }))}
```